# Return base class instance from derive class calls

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

For fun, I'm writing up a generic board game class that can be tailored to various games. It includes a lot of general functionality (filling in cells, rotating, flipping, applying lists of moves, etc).

The base class is generic so that you may specify what each cell should be filled with.

```
public class Board<T> { /* various usefule routines that return new instances of Board<T> */ }
```

I'm starting with a game of TicTacToe, declared like so:

```
public enum TicTacMove { Empty, X, O };

public class TicTacToe : Board<TicTacMove> { /* ... */ }
```

Where I'm running into trouble is casting this generic version returned by base routines back to the derived class - I simply can't.

When I try to assign the value of the base functions to the derived class, I get:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'BoardGames.Board' to 'BoardGames.TicTacToe.TicTacToe'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So, I explicitly cast it, which then gives me an InvalidCastException:

> Unable to cast object of type 'BoardGames.Board`1[BoardGames.TicTacToe.TicTacMove]' to type 'BoardGames.TicTacToe.TicTacToe'

If my class held mutable data I could simply alter the data in place and not worry about it; my question is how to achieve this by returning a new instance so that each instance is immutable.

Edit:
The base class, for example, has this constructor:

```
 public Board(Board<T> Source, IEnumerable<(int Index, T Value)> Changes)
```

Calling this constructor from the derived class TicTacToe does not yield a new instance of TicTacToe but instead yields an instance of Board, which can then not be cast back to TicTacToe.

Comment: Could you share the code where you get this exception from ?

Comment: What do you mean by `try to assign the value of the base functions to the derived class`? Do you have a specific code line that throws this exception which you could add?

Comment: Added another snippet

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.

Because you are not allowed to cast from a base class back to a derived class, the functions which return a new instance must be called as base constructors from derived constructors.

To simplify things I made a single constructor in the base class which returns a modified instance.

In the derived classes, I implement a single private constructor that takes a list of changes to make. This has the advantage that it's pretty much boilerplate.

Then each derived class is able to call a constructor of its own type, which then passes the work to the base class constructor. This avoids the casting issues I was running into.

As an example (rough pseudocode ahead)

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
  protected BaseClass(BaseClass Source, var changes...) ...
}

public class DerivedClass {
  private DerivedClass(DerivedClass Source, var changes)
    : BaseClass(Source, changes) { }

public DerivedClass MakeChange(var change) {
  ...set up changed values...
  return new DerivedClass(this, changes)
  }
}
```